# Struct not seeing the pointer?

Tags: c

I have to allocate memory dinamically, every other list i see, the struct is coded like that.. don't know what's wrong. The struct is declared like:

```
struct CAD
{
    char hash_atual[TAM_HASH];

    char hash_anterior[TAM_HASH];

    char timestamp[TAM_TEMP];

    ALUNOS registros[REG_MAX];

    struct CAD *prox;

};

typedef struct CAD CADEIA;
```

...

```
CADEIA** criar_cadeia(CADEIA **c)
{
    CADEIA *novo;
    char hash[TAM_HASH], caracteres[62];

    c = (CADEIA**)malloc(sizeof(CADEIA*));
    novo = (CADEIA*)malloc(sizeof(CADEIA));
```

...

```
    strcpy(novo->hash_atual, hash);
    strcpy(novo->prox->hash_anterior, novo->hash_atual); --->problem here
```

Comment: where do you initialize `prox` before dereferencing it?

Comment: If you think that giant wild-card of `...` in your code isn't relevant, think again. As presented, this is not conclusively answerable, and at-best only sheer guesses will abound.

Comment: there are a lot of linked lists questions & examples on the site.

Comment: I think the assignment `c = (CADEIA**)...` is not the way it's intended to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `novo->prox` is a pointer to `struct CAD` which is not initialized, hence it may contain garbage value. Before accessing `novo->prox` you should either set it to point to a valid memory address.

Comment: oh thank i solved thanks to you by doing this
       novo->prox = (CADEIA*)malloc(sizeof(CADEIA)); i just dont understand why, cause in my head when u allocate memory for novo you're already allocating memory for novo->prox